# Calling a function within a function and returning a string

Tags: json, swift, function

I have a function called `getEarthquake()` that parses JSON using SwiftyJSON and returns all of the organized information (such as `title`, `magnitude`, and `time`) into an `NSMutableArray` called `info`.

```
var info = NSMutableArray()

    func getEarthquake(completion: (results : NSMutableArray) ->Void) {
        DataManager.getEarthquakeDataFromFileWithSuccess {
            (data) -> Void in
            let json = JSON(data: data)
            if var JsonArray =  json.array {
                JsonArray.removeAtIndex(0)
                for appDict in JsonArray {
                    var mag: String? = appDict["mag"].stringValue
                    var title: String? = appDict["title"].stringValue
                    var time: String? = appDict["time"].stringValue
                    var information = AppModel(title: title, magnitude: mag, time1: time)
                    info.addObject(information)
               //     info.removeRange(3...48)

                    completion(results: info)
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

I created another function called `getEarthquake2()` which calls `getEarthquake()` and retrieves `info`. In `getEarthquake2()` I want it to return only `title1`, which is a `String`. However my attempts result only in `title1` being `nil` by the time is it returned.

```
func getEarthquake2()->String? {
    var title1: String?
    getEarthquake{ (info) in

        var title = info[0].title
        title1 = title

    }

   return title1

}
```

Can someone guide me in the right direction upon making `getEarthquake2()`successfully return `title1` that doesn't return nil? (I'm sure it's not a matter of `Info` being nil, as it gets populated at the end of `getEarthquake()`.)

My AppModel.swift file where I can easily organize my code:

```
import Foundation
class AppModel: NSObject, Printable {
    let title: String
    let magnitude: String
    let time1: String

    override var description: String {
        return "TITLE: \(title), TIME: \(time1), MAG: \(magnitude)"
    }
    init(title: String?, magnitude: String?, time1: String?) {
        self.title = title ?? ""
        self.time1 = time1 ?? ""
        self.magnitude = magnitude ?? ""
    }

}
```

My DataManager.swift file where I call the web service:

```
import Foundation
let earthquakeURL = "http://www.kuakes.com/json/"
class DataManager {
    class func getEarthquakeDataFromFileWithSuccess(success: ((websiteData: NSData) -> Void)) {
        //1
        loadDataFromURL(NSURL(string: earthquakeURL)!, completion:{(data, error) -> Void in
            //2
            if let urlData = data {
                //3
                success(websiteData: urlData)
            }
            else {
                println("nothing")
            }
        })
    }
    class func loadDataFromURL(url: NSURL, completion:(data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void) {
        var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        // Use NSURLSession to get data from an NSURL
        let loadDataTask = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if let responseError = error {
                completion(data: nil, error: responseError)
            } else if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                if httpResponse.statusCode != 200 {
                    var statusError = NSError(domain:"com.kuakes", code:httpResponse.statusCode, userInfo:[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "HTTP status code has unexpected value."])
                    completion(data: nil, error: statusError)
                } else {
                    completion(data: data, error: nil)
                }
            }
        })

        loadDataTask.resume()
    }







}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `getEarthquake2` you forget to cast your object to `AppModel`:

```
func getEarthquake2() -> String? {
    var title1: String?

    getEarthquake { info in
        let title = (info[0] as! AppModel).title
        title1 = title
    }

    return title1
}
```

Comment: I apologize, I typed my question in a hurry and I incorrectly asked my question. My bad :( Title does not return nil, it successfully gets populated from my info array. My problem is that title1 returns nil at the end of `getEarthquake2()`. Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: @videoperson but it doesn't return `nil` for me, please checkout this in Xcode playground: https://gist.github.com/marcioadr88/65a5b210b960e52f987f